# How to avoid to open an activity on android?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app for Android using Android studio. I have two activities; the first one to configure the app (it must appear only the first time that app is launched), the second activity is to log in to the app.

The problem is: I want to show the "config activity" at the first launch, and after that the "login activity" must appear, but I don't know how to do this. I tried to put a conditional into the "config activity" to force the second (login) to put it to work. But it doesn't work.

Can you explain me some things about this topic?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Yout main Activity, in the onCreate() method, must use a preference to see if running for the first time. If so, it should launch the config activity and also call `finish()`. The user won't notice that the main activity didn't launch.

Something like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if(prefs.getBoolean("first_time", true))
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit()
        .putBoolean("first_time", false);
    editor.commit();
    finish();

     // launch the config activity
    startActivity(new Intent(this, ConfigActivity.class));
}
```